# Create provisioning profile without real device?

Tags: xcode7, profile, provisioning

I need to make archive for my app to upload it on iTunes store but the problem is I don't have a physical device like "iphone/Ipade" tried with Generic deivce but it doesn't work don't have UDID to register anyway.
Xcode7

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can create a provisioning profile by going into Xcode Preferences and adding it.

To start with, press Command + comma to enter preferences. Go ahead and navigate to the Accounts tab and log into your Apple ID.

Proceed to click on view details, and simply create a iOS Development Signing Identity. Afterwards, simply go back to the root area of your project and click on 'Fix Issue - No provisioning profile found'

**EDIT:** If you don't have a physical iDevice, you'll need to register an Apple Developer Account on their developer site. Afterwards, simply follow this tutorial to proceed: [Tutorial](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/mobile/ios-application-provisioning-requirements/)

Hope that helped :3

Comment: that's already done I have iOS Development/Distribution certificate and when I click fix issue like you mention popup appears with that message"No Devices Registered"

Comment: is that 3rd party service? register multi lists! after I test the links its gives me "This service is no longer available."

Comment: Update2: I tried to build profile with UDID that I found on web I created profile and the trick goes well but after trying to Archive the project there's problem appears " linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" so the build failed

Comment: and just to know I have Apple Developer Account

Comment: that tutorial requires a device though...how to do it?

Comment: Link no longer works, better to copy in the important steps when you can.